# yq replace value keep rest intact

Tags: yaml, yq

I want just to replace a value in a multi .yaml file with yq and leaving the rest of the document intact. So the question is how do i replace the value of the `image` key only when the above key value contains `name: node-red` i have tried:

```
yq '.spec.template.spec.containers[] | select(.name = "node-red") | .image |= "test"' ./test.yaml`
```

with this yaml:

```yaml
---
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: node-red
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-private
  rules:
    - host: node-red.k8s.lan
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/"
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: node-red
                port:
                  number: 1880

---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: node-red
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: node-red
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: node-red
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: node-red
          image: "cir.domain.com/node-red:84"
```

the output is:

```yaml
name: node-red
image: "test"
```

What I want is a yaml output with only a updated value in the image key like this:

```yaml
---
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: node-red
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-private
  rules:
    - host: node-red.k8s.lan
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/"
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: node-red
                port:
                  number: 1880

---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: node-red
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: node-red
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: node-red
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: node-red
          image: "test"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep the context by including the traversal and selection into the LHS of the assignment/update, ie. putting parentheses around all of it:

```bash
yq '(.spec.template.spec.containers[] | select(.name == "node-red") | .image) |= "test"'
```

In order to prevent the creation of elements previously not present in one of the documents, add filters using `select` accordingly, e.g.:

```bash
yq '(.spec | select(.template).template.spec.containers[] | select(.name == "node-red").image) |= "test"'
```

Note that in any case it should read `==` not `=` when checking for equality.

Comment: Thank you very much, this indeed works. I'll have to dig into it a bit more because I don't really understand what it all does. for example when should you use parentheses and why. Why `(.template)` with parentheses.

Comment: @theautomation In the case of `select(.template)` the `.template` part is the argument to the `select(‌...)` function which passes on its input unchanged if the condition given as parameter evaluates to `true`. So, if `.template` exists (and is neither `null` or `false`) inside a given `.spec` (the input), it will be passed on (as output), such that the following `.template.spec.containers[]` can keep on traversing the structure.

Comment: @theautomation As for the other parentheses (especially those used on the LHS in the update), they set the scope for the current context. Any traversal happening inside them is restored when the interpreter exits (to the previous context).